# converting comma separated string to a list

Tags: php, mysql

I am geeting the results like `ali,aliiii,asd` by echoing `$row['GROUP_CONCAT(mem_name)'];`.

How can I echo them like a list so that I can add anchor tag on click functions etc.i have the query

```
$sql=mysql_query("
    SELECT cat_id, GROUP_CONCAT(mem_name)  
    FROM o_newcatmem GROUP BY cat_id
");
```

I want the resuts to b displayed like this:

```
ali
aliiii
asd
```

Comment: The reasonable approach would be to select them from the database as separate values instead of a single concatenated value.

Comment: thanks,i can i select them as  separate values?

Answer (score 2):

You have a `$string` like this

```
$string = "ali,aliiii,asd";
echo "<pre>";
```

You have three options:

1. You can use `str_getcsv` to convert CSV string to array

   ```
   $list = str_getcsv($string);
   foreach ( $list as $var ) {
       echo $var, "\n";
   }
   ```
2. Convert them to array using `explode`

   ```
   $list = explode(",", $string);
   echo implode("\n", $list);
   ```
3. Use just use `str_replace`

   ```
   $list = str_replace(",", "\n", $string);
   echo $list;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function has a SEPARATOR keywords.

- You can use `GROUP_CONCAT(mem_name SEPARATOR ',')  AS mems_name` in your SQL statement.
- Use separator that does not exist in `mem_name` field.
- Use alias `AS mems_name`, so your PHP code looks simple, like `$row['mems_name']`.

In your PHP just [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) data by your separator `$list = explode('|', $row['mems_name']);`.

Comment: thanks,how to  use like like $row['mems_name']. in        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT cat_id, GROUP_CONCAT(mem_name)  FROM o_newcatmem GROUP BY cat_id ");

Comment: Didn't work? What is the error? Have you tried like this: `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT cat_id, GROUP_CONCAT(mem_name SEPARATOR ',') AS mems_name FROM o_newcatmem GROUP BY cat_id");`

Comment: $sql=mysql_query("SELECT cat_id, GROUP_CONCAT(mem_name SEPARATOR ',') AS mems_name FROM o_newcatmem GROUP BY cat_id ");

            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

                $mem_name=$row['mems_name'];
                $list = str_replace(",", "\n",$mem_names);
                echo $list; 

its howed the result as
            ali aliiii  //just seprtd two resultd
            asdf
            i also want to add the anchr tag to these outputs

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Example 1
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2

// Example 2
$data = "foo:*:1023:1000::/home/foo:/bin/sh";
list($user, $pass, $uid, $gid, $gecos, $home, $shell) = explode(":", $data);
echo $user; // foo
echo $pass; // *

?>
```